# How this non-zero matrix can be transformed to a row-echelon matrix?

Tags: matrices

The procedure introduced in the proof of the following theorem, probably does not work generally!

[image]

Given the matrix $$A= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 7 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 5 \\
1 & -3 & -1 & -10 & \alpha \end{array} \right), $$ I arrived at the matrix $$B= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 7 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \alpha+\frac{35}{2} \end{array} \right). $$

The original problem is to determine $\alpha$ such that in a row-echelon form of A, the stairstep reaches the bottom. The book says $\alpha =1$ but it is valid for any $\alpha \ne -\frac{35}{2}$?

Comment: As an aside, how did you get from $A$ to $B$?  In particular the second row of $B$?  Why did you not end up with a pivot in the second column?

Comment: @JMoravitz, after *several* operations. Would you want me to recalculate and add it to OP?

Comment: @JMoravitz, the main problem still remains that $\alpha$ is not restricted to one value; it is any value such that $\alpha+r \ne 0$ in $[.]_{44}$

Comment: Given that the two matrices $A$ and $B$ do not rowreduce to the same matrix, there *must* have been some error.  The rref of $A$ has a pivot in the second column while the rref of $B$ does not.  This can be seen immediately by the fact that the first two columns are nonzero and not multiples of one another.

Comment: @JMoravitz, sorry I didn't get it. I don't know what "rref" and "pivot" mean in matrix. Also, first two columns are equal (so multiple of each other) and it is possible that entries of first row in several columns be nonzero with rest entries of those columns be zero.

Comment: rref is shorthand for "reduced row echelon form" and a pivot in the rref of a matrix is the furthest left nonzero entry of a row such that all other entries in its column are zero and all entries down and/or to the left are zero.  Alternatively, it is the bottommost nonzero entry of a column with all other entries in its column zero and all entries down and/or to the left are zero.  If you say the first two columns are equal, then check to make sure that you wrote down $A$ correctly, because the first two columns of $A$ are certainly not equal.

Comment: $A$ is same as the book. I have to recalculate $B$ again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a reminder, the elementary row operations are the following:

- multiply any row by a nonzero number
- add to a row a multiple of any *other* row or rows
- swap two rows

You may *not* add a constant number to every entry of a row (unless you have a row of all ones).  You may *not* swap two columns.  In general, you may not do anything except those three operations already mentioned.

For notation, by $r_1+3r_2\mapsto r_1$ I mean to create the new first row by taking the former first row and adding three times the second row to it.  By $r_1\leftrightarrow r_3$ I mean swap the positions of rows one and three.  By $2r_3\mapsto r_3$ I mean create the new row three by taking the former row three and multiplying every entry by two.

We begin with $A= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 7 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 5 \\
1 & -3 & -1 & -10 & \alpha \end{array} \right)$

Apply the row operations $\begin{cases}r_2-2r_1\mapsto r_2\\
r_3-r_1\mapsto r_3\\
r_4-r_1\mapsto r_4\end{cases}$ to then get to the form:

$\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&0&1&4\\
0&-2&0&2&-1\\
0&0&1&-1&1\\
0&-4&-1&-11&\alpha-4\end{pmatrix}$

Now that the firstrow, first column entry is a $1$ and all entries down and to the left are zero, we have finished "pivoting" around that entry, and so we try to start pivoting around the next position in the "staircase", namely the second row second column entry.

Applying the row operation $-\frac{1}{2}r_2\mapsto r_2$, we get:

$\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&0&1&4\\
0&1&0&-1&\frac{1}{2}\\
0&0&1&-1&1\\
0&-4&-1&-11&\alpha-4\end{pmatrix}$

We then finish pivoting around the second row second column entry with the row operations:  $\begin{cases} r_1-r_2\mapsto r_1\\ r_4+4r_2\mapsto r_4\end{cases}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&2&\frac{7}{2}\\
0&1&0&-1&\frac{1}{2}\\
0&0&1&-1&1\\
0&0&-1&-15&\alpha-2\end{pmatrix}$

Now we have finished pivoting around row2 column2.  We now attempt to start pivoting around the next position in the "staircase", row3 column3.  As luck would have it, it is already a one, so we go straight to clearing out the rest of its column.

Continue the row reduction process and reach a conclusion.  You will find that with $A$ as you have written it, $\alpha$ can be anything.

---

As alluded to above in the comments, given a matrix $A$ and a matrix $B$ such that $B$ is created via the result of a sequence of elementary row operations on $A$, you will necessarily have $rref(A)=rref(B)$.  Furthermore, the reduced row echelon form of a matrix $A$ is unique.

At a glance, your matrix $B$ could not have come from elementary operations on $A$ because the first two columns of $B$ were identical but the first two columns of $A$ were not.  Since the first two columns of $A$ were not multiples of one another and are nonzero, that implies that the first and second column in the rref form of $A$ should have a pivot (a furthest left nonzero entry with all entries down and to the left zero)

Throughout your study of linear algebra, you will find yourself looking at the rref form of a matrix quite often as it imparts a great deal of information: linear independence of columns, linear independence of rows, nullspace, columnspace, ...  In particular, the locations of pivots reveal quite a bit of that information.

Specifically, if you have a matrix $A=[v_1,v_2,v_3,\dots,v_k]$ with $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_k$ column vectors of the same dimension, letting $V_0=\{0\}$ and $V_i = span[v_1,\dots,v_i]$, there is guaranteed to be a pivot in the $i^{th}$ column of the rref of $A$ if and only if $dim(V_i)>dim(V_{i-1})$.  In other words, if $v_i$ is not in the span of $v_1,\dots,v_{i-1}$.

Comment: I edited the post and the $\alpha$ won't be restricted to 1. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Liebe as a complete aside, you can reduce matrices with a calculator or sites like [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=rref+{{1,1,0,1,4},{2,0,0,4,7},{1,1,1,0,5},{1,-3,-1,-10,x}}) to check your work.  Any submitted assignments however, the scratch work and necessary steps should all be shown, but this is a good way to check your answers.

Comment: I entered x=1 but didn't work!

Comment: @Liebe just replace $x$ by $1$ in the query [like so](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=rref+{{1,1,0,1,4},{2,0,0,4,7},{1,1,1,0,5},{1,-3,-1,-10,1}}).  Or you could try other ways like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=rref+{{1,1,0,1,4},{2,0,0,4,7},{1,1,1,0,5},{1,-3,-1,-10,x}}+when+x%3D1) which apparently worked too.  The point is that the first four columns of your matrix as you have written it are linearly independent and so it doesn't matter what the fifth column is.  Again, unless you made a transcription error someplace.

Answer (score 0):

Just exchange rows 2 and 4. 
Exchange of rows is an allowed elementary operation.

You should end up with $\DeclareMathOperator{rank}{rank}\rank (A)$ non zero rows.

Comment: exchange of rows 2 and 4 didn't work. exchange of rows 2 and 3 works but and its solution doesn't depend on $\alpha$, but the book say that must $\alpha=1$!

Comment: The idea is to bring one of the rows with an earlier leading non-zero element above. See sentence 3 of the procedure. If you do not get your book solution you might have made a mistake in between.

Comment: By exchange of rows 2 and 3 finally $C= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 7 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \alpha+27 \end{array} \right).$; valid for any value of $\alpha \ne -27$.